# CSRF cookie not set [Django/AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs, django, csrf, django-rest-framework-jwt

First of all, this is not a duplicate question. I have tried all the related posts on stackoverflow but could not find a solution.

I have a Django app for the backend and and AngularJS app for the frontend. I am using `djangorestframework-jwt` for API authentication. I have an API endpoint that does not require any authentication and I am getting `CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set` error on the browser only for this endpoint.

In my django settings I have:

`ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

and it does not include any `CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE`, `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY`, or `SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE` settings.

The `djangorestframework-jwt` settings is:

```
JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_SECRET_KEY': SECRET_KEY,
    'JWT_ALGORITHM': 'HS256',
    'JWT_VERIFY': True,
    'JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION': True,
    'JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(seconds=3000),
    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'refresh-token'
}
```

I noticed that in the browser cookies if there is any `refresh-token` key then the endpoint works just fine. The problem arises when that key is not present in the browser cookies. I set `'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None` or removed the following lines:

```
'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': 'refresh-token'
```

from the `JWT_AUTH` settings but no luck.

I also tried `@csrf_excempt` for that endpoint but that did not work either.

Interestingly, when I send the request from postman it works.

Here is the request I am sending from the frontend:

```
$http({
    url: url,
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: data
})
```

I would like to know why I am getting the error when `refresh_token` key is not present in the browser cookies and how to solve this issue.

Comment: what error are you getting? and any exceptions?

Comment: I am getting `CSRF Failed: CSRF cookie not set.` on the browser.

Comment: I just tried but that does not work either.

Comment: you removed the csrf middleware, still it says CSRF Failed?

Comment: Yes, I commented out that line and restarted the server. Then I sent the request from the frontend after refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by adding `'X-CSRFToken': $cookies.get("csrftoken")` to the Http request header, so the request now look like:

```
$http({
    url: url,
    method: "PUT",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': $cookies.get("csrftoken")
    },
    data: data
})
```